# Eclipse C++: How do I insert inline assembly code?

Tags: assembly, x86, g++, inline-assembly

I have a project in C ++, and I want to insert blocks of code in assembly.
What solutions can I use?
The compiler that I use g ++ and my cpu is a i5.

So far I tried:

```
void f1(int a){
    asm(
        "mov edx,4"
    );
}
............
```

when I compile I get this error:

```
error: unknown use of instruction mnemonic without a size suffix
```

I tried more examples that I found on google but each of them gives me a different error.

EDIT2:

```
void f1(int a) {
    int r = 0;
    cout << "start";
    __asm__(
            "movl %edx,4;"
    );
    cout << r;
    cout << a;
    cout << "end";
}

int main(){
    f1(2);
    return 1;
}
```

Build succesfully but the output is empty... Doesn't print nothing... However if remove the __asm_(..), then the outpus is the following: "start02end"... why with the asm block doesn't print nothing??

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP surely didn't even try to read any documentation.

Comment: Try AT&T syntax, you probably won't like it though. You could also use YASM or whatever and assemble some code separately, then link  it in.

Comment: `gcc` inline assembly is a complicated matter. Go read the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) and come back if you have a more specific question. Apart from using separate asm module, you could consider builtin vector support and intrinsics (you didn't say what you wanted to do with your asm code). PS: you can switch to intel syntax using `-masm=intel`.

Answer (score 1):

gcc inline assembly is a complicated matter. Go read the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) for details. Even when it seems to be working, it may mysteriously fail under different circumstances. You really need to know what you are doing.

That said, here is a quick overview: `gcc` does not parse your asm block at all, it considers it to be a black box. You need to describe it in terms of what inputs it expects, what outputs it provides and what state it destroys.

Your example of loading 4 into `edx` makes no sense, you are just overwriting a register without knowing what that register is used for by the compiler. You can't expect any particular result from that code. Also, your at&t translation (`movl %edx, 4`) is wrong, since at&t expects operands in reversed order, and immediates need a `$` prefix. As such, your code writes the contents of `edx` into memory location `4` which will segfault.

A valid (but still meaningless) example is:

```
__asm__("movl $4, %%edx" : : : "edx");
```

This will load `4` into `edx`, while also telling the compiler that you destroyed the previous value of `edx`. The instruction will be included in the resulting program, but it will have no effect since `edx` isn't used and the asm block has no output.

A somewhat more interesting example inserted into your example:

```
void f1(int a) {
    int r = 0;
    cout << "start";
    __asm__("addl $1, %0" : "+d" (a));
    cout << r;
    cout << a;
    cout << "end";
}
```

This will ask the compiler to put the value of `a` into register `edx` (signalled by the `d` constraint letter), then substitute `%edx` into the asm block for `%0` (referring to operand 0) and finally write back from `%edx` into `a` again. The `+` modifier signals a read-write operand. This code will thus print `start03end`.

As said in the comments, make sure you really need inline assembly and can not use vector supports, intrinsics or separate assembly module instead.

Comment: The `d` is only for the constraints, the clobber list uses the full register name.